# Sign in using twitter. OAuth or Xauth using linq2twitter

Tags: c#, linq-to-twitter

For the past few days, I am struggling with this issue. At this moment, I have a simple c# console app. Ultimately, I want to make a small library to be reused in mobile apps for sign in with twitter, but that is a problem for later. At this moment, I have the following code, that should in theory allow me to sign in to twitter.

```
var auth = new XAuthAuthorizer()
                       {
                          Credentials = new XAuthCredentials()
                                             {
                                                 UserName = "username",
                                                 Password = "supersecretpassword",
                                                 ConsumerKey = "2131341234Q123123",
                                                 ConsumerSecret = "671723458671253481234"
                                             }
                       };

        auth.Authorize();

        using (var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth))
        {
            //Log
            twitterCtx.Log = Console.Out;

            var users =
                (from tweet in twitterCtx.User
                 where tweet.Type == UserType.Search &&
                       tweet.ScreenName == ""
                 select tweet)
                .ToList();

            users.ForEach(user =>
            {
                var status =
                    user.Protected || user.Status == null ?
                        "Status Unavailable" :
                        user.Status.Text;

                Console.WriteLine(
                    "ID: {0}, Name: {1}\nLast Tweet: {2}\n",
                    user.Identifier.UserID, user.Identifier.ScreenName, status);
            });
```

I have not yet sent a XAuth access request to twitter. (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth)
This is after all a test app to see how it's done.

My Question is this. Can I allow my users to give their username and password for twitter and sign in without using Xauth ? How do I do this if it is possible... Is it a better solution ? If you can give me examples of how to do this using linq2twitter, I would be very great full. I am a rookie developer and I am running into walls everywhere... Also, the given code here, will this work if I got Xauth access from twitter ?

Thank you all in advance. I am really stuck and google is starting to hate me by now...

EDIT...

I found this link  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter
But I got a 401 Unauthorized return... dont know why, if you spot something wrong let me know. I think its the callback url, but I am a bit unsure

```
string oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";
        TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        string oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(ts.TotalSeconds).ToString();

        string oauth_version = "1.0";
        string oauth_consumer_key = "123123412341235";
        string oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));

        SortedDictionary<string, string> sd = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();

        sd.Add("oauth_version", oauth_version);
        sd.Add("oauth_consumer_key", oauth_consumer_key);
        sd.Add("oauth_nonce", oauth_nonce);
        sd.Add("oauth_signature_method", oauth_signature_method);
        sd.Add("oauth_timestamp", oauth_timestamp);
        UrlEntity callback = new UrlEntity();
        callback.Url = @"http://127.0.0.1";
        string encodedCallbackUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(callback.Url);
        sd.Add("oauth_callback",encodedCallbackUrl);

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: randomAgent HTTP Client");
        wc.Headers.Add("Host: api.twitter.com");
        wc.Headers.Add(@"Accept: */*");
        UrlEntity url = new UrlEntity();
        url.Url = @"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
        string signature = CreateSignature(url, sd);
        sd.Add("oauth_signature",signature);
        string dataValues = "";
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in sd)
        {
            dataValues += pair.Key + "='" + pair.Value + "',";
        }
        dataValues = dataValues.Substring(0, dataValues.Length - 1); // cuts off the last,
        string headerVal = " Oauth " + dataValues;
        wc.Headers.Add("Authorization",headerVal);
        wc.UploadString(@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "");
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += WcOnDownloadStringCompleted;
```

I dont yet understand what to use for the callback url.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, you are using the library (dlls...), for the access on the twitter, and the Twitter does not allow that you be authorized without oAuth (at least I do not know any other way).

And the Application that you make on [TwitterDev](http://dev.twitter.com) is very important ;D. I have the same error that you have now, but I think!. Try the follow code in the TwitterDev:

```
1 -Access level       Read, write, and direct messages 
2 -Consumer key       your_consumer_key
3 -Consumer secret    your_very_large_consumer_secret_key
4 -Request token URL  https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
5 -Authorize URL      https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize
6 -Access token URL   https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token
7 -Callback URL       https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize
Sign in with Twitter    Yes
```

My errors are on the line 4,5,6 and 7...
Even more