# 401 unauthorize twitter api 1.1 (https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token)

Tags: c#, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have a problem while trying to authenticate to Twitter API.

I based on Suresh implementation :
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/add-twitter-login-authentication-to.html

My urls are :

```
public const string REQUEST_TOKEN = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
public const string AUTHORIZE = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";
public const string ACCESS_TOKEN = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
```

Here is the result of my signature base:

```
GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_consumer_key%3Dvalue%26oauth_nonce%3D4448975%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1377452265%26oauth_token%3Dvalue%26oauth_version%3D1.0
```

Here is my request :

```
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_consumer_key="consumer_key_value"&oauth_nonce=4448975&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1377452265&oauth_token="token_value"&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=pI/fiPW7ddgF7sCQnUQINmQrMLo=
```

If I paste this value to my browser, I receive "Failed to validate oauth signature and token"

The time is correctly configure and the credentials are the good ones for sure.

I'm actually working on localhost and I don't fill the callback.

Is somebody got an idea on that problems?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I posted a similar question. I include the link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396917/sign-in-using-twitter-oauth-or-xauth-using-linq2twitter)

Comment: I don't think that comes from the callback. I'll try some more ways and if I don't manage I think I will use LinkToTwitter but it's a heavier solution than Suresh one, that's my problem

Comment: As it is, I am stuck with this. I have no idea what to do. I just keep getting a 401 Unauthorized error. I have no idea where I went wrong.

Comment: I just want to use Twitter for a sign in flow so I prefer don't use any libraries, someone has got a class for getting the good request header?

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do.. Sign in with twitter then boom back to the app. But this is so bloody hard and stupid.... These links are what I am working from... [implementing](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter),[signature](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature), and [Authorizing](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request)